# Callback is not a function in nodeJS for multiple variables returning?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am trying to return two variables in a callback function and it throws callback is not a function error but when returning single variable works fine

```
function TranslatetoHindi(text,suggestion,callback) {
translatedText = text
stringify = JSON.stringify(suggestion)
*--------------------
 --------------------code block here --------*
        callback(translatedText,stringify)
}
```

callback(translatedText,stringify) is throwing the error.This is the function call statement

```
TranslatetoHindi(var1,var2,function(returnedText, returned) 
{
---some code here which uses var1 and var2 ----
}
```

Comment: Your callback looks fine, what's the error?

Comment: 'callback(translatedText, stringify)
            ^
    TypeError: callback is not a function'

Comment: Its throwing this error @James

Comment: It would be more conventional in your `callback` to use `returnedText` and `returned` rather than the arguments passed in with the callback: `var1` and `var2`. It shouldn't throw an error though, assuming your vars are defined in the same scope as where you call `TranslatetoHindi`.

Comment: @Karthikeyan_kk [here's your code working](https://repl.it/KNao/0), as I said as it stands it looks fine to me. Your example can't reflect your actual code if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that javascript is misreading your function input when you open the curly brace on the next line:

```
TranslatetoHindi(var1,var2,function(returnedText, returned) 
{
---some code here which uses var1 and var2 ----
}
```

Javascript often tries to *help* when code looks wrong by adding semicolons, etc. Try this form and see if it works:

```
TranslatetoHindi(var1,var2,function(returnedText, returned) {
---some code here which uses var1 and var2 ----
});
```

With the open brace on the same line as the function to make sure there's no confusion.

Comment: Although it's evident in the example, the code wouldn't run if that were the case - my guess is that's just a typo.

Comment: @James, maybe so. But not knowing the context, I thought it was possible, depending what came before and after.

Comment: my point is there would be a more obvious error if that was the case i.e. `Unexpected token`. The code wouldn't get as far as telling the OP that their callback is not a function. My guess is the OP isn't passing in the correct params but, as you say, without more context it's difficult to answer.